# Create own Css commands

Tags: css

Is there a way to make my own CSS commands.

For example, the command:

```
margin:0 auto
```

Normally centers a div in relation to the parent.

Now, say for example, I wanted to make a new command, like:

```
Location:Center
```

and this command would center the div in relation to the screen, rather than the parent.

My question is not how difficult it would be to implement the above CSS, but is it possible to actually make my own CSS, or is this all interpreted by the browsers and no possibility of adding new commands.

I have tried googling a few phrases like 'make my own css commands' or 'custom css commands', but nothing has come up...

Comment: No, you can't make up your own CSS. But you can use a CSS preprocessor to do something similar.

Comment: You can achieve it with the help of css pre-processors such as SASS or Less, they allow to store data in variables and mixins then re-use them over and over within the project.

Comment: You need to use classes for this. `:)` This question is like, you are asking if you can create your own HTML elements. The answer is NO.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - but one can create their own HTML elements, can they not? http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/ both appear to indicate this to be perfectly acceptable, as does past experience.

Comment: Nice one @enhzflep... `#ShadowDOM`

Comment: If you have a sophisticated enough server side language (you know, the usual, PHP, ASP.NET etc) you can program your own stylesheet. Just output the http header for `text/css` and you're all set.

Comment: The CSS Houdini project is looking to things like this. From their [Wiki](https://wiki.css-houdini.org/) here's the [current plan for custom properties](https://wiki.css-houdini.org/_detail/registerproperty.jpg?id=custom-properties)